# Limit the selection of CheckBoxes in Java

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, actionevent

I have multiple checkboxes in my program. I want the user to select only 3 checkboxes and when 3 of them are checked, others should be disabled. Additionally, when one is unchecked, then all others should be enabled.

Comment: A `counter` with `counter++` and `counter--` ?

Comment: You want a circularly linked list.

Comment: Please describe with the particular methods and classes used. I know the logical part but don't know the coding.

Comment: [java.util.List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html); [Trail: Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)

Comment: use PropertychangeListener to check how many checkbox is selected?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with an almost complete source code:

```java
public class TestProgram {

    public static JCheckBox[] checkList = new JCheckBox[10];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Listener listener = new Listener();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            checkList[i] = new JCheckBox("CheckBox-" + i);
            checkList[i].addItemListener(listener);
        }

        //
        // The rest of the GUI layout job ...
        //
    }

    static class Listener implements ItemListener {

        private final int MAX_SELECTIONS = 3;

        private int selectionCounter = 0;

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            JCheckBox source = (JCheckBox) e.getSource();

            if (source.isSelected()) {
                selectionCounter++;
                // check for max selections:
                if (selectionCounter == MAX_SELECTIONS)
                    for (JCheckBox box: checkList)
                        if (!box.isSelected())
                            box.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else {
                selectionCounter--;
                // check for less than max selections:
                if (selectionCounter < MAX_SELECTIONS)
                    for (JCheckBox box: checkList)
                        box.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think "MAX_SELECTIONS" and "selectionCounter" might need to be global, but this looks like code which is on the right track +1.

Comment: It could be, but I intended to place all the bounding logic in one class, which is the `Listener` class that handles the selection-bounding.

Answer (score 1):

Set the signle action listener on check boxes. Inside the listener code, you can read the state of all boxes involved (`isSelected()`) into separate boolean variables and make a decision which ones should be disable or enabled (`setEnabled()`).

Answer (score -1):

To  stop check box from multiple selections  please apply.  Same  buttongroup  to each check box

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked.